# Within a DLL function returning memory, where to allocate and where to deallocate?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dll

I'm extremely new to DLL writing/usage, and have written a function within the DLL that accepts a string, and returns another string to the executable as output.

```
#define DECL_EXPORT  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 

DECL_EXPORT char * organizeArgs(const char * args) {
    uint32 outputLen;
    ... 
    char * result = new char[outputLen];
    ...
    return result;
}
```

The easiest way for me was to allocate the memory in the DLL and return it to the executable to deallocate, but I'm reading that this is generally bad as it'll break, when the allocation code between dll and exe are not identical.  Trying to avoid allocating in the dll and deallocating in the executable is making this function and how it's used much more complex.

How should this type of allocation/deallocation be handled?

I have a couple of theories but both of them feel kind of terrible:

- Calculating the size of the output in a separate dll function call, so the caller can allocate that much memory for the output and provide it to the dll.  This seems like the most sane solution, but requires running the analysis code twice:

```
DECL_EXPORT uint32 organizeArgsSize(const char * args) { 
    ...
    return size; 
}

DECL_EXPORT char * organizeArgs(const char * args, char * outputBuffer) { 
    ...
    return outputBuffer;
}
```

- Allocate on the dll and return a pointer that the executable isn't expected to free, which is valid until overwritten by a second call of the dll's function.  This has the best ergonomics for the caller I think, but since I'm multi-threading, this would require `thread_local` storage.  I'm still trying to research if using `thread_local` in a dll is acceptable and haven't found anything:

```
DECL_EXPORT const char * organizeArgs(const char * args) { 
    thread_local std::string buffer;
    ...
    return buffer.c_str();
}
```

I imagine something like this comes up a lot in DLL writing, and I'm making it out to be more hard than it actually is.  How is it usually done?

Comment: One function to *acquire* a resources, one to *release* it.

Comment: MS provide a set of functions for allocating and free memory across a (potential) ABI boundary see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/comparing-memory-allocation-methods  You need to tell the user of the function that allocates memory what function to use to free it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm so prepared to avoid having heap I can't delete[] that I have done crimes  https://hastebin.com/uzeqivivug.cpp

Comment: FYI -- If this is DLL is supposed to be used by other languages, then the data types you're using should be ones that Windows recognizes universally, i.e. `LONG`, `LPCSTR`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method is to change your function to the following:

```
DECL_EXPORT LONG organizeArgs(LPCSTR args, LPSTR outbuf, LONG length);
```

Then the API could be documented like this:

```
args - is the set of arguments
outbuf - is the output buffer or NULL
length - length of the output buffer, ignored if outbuf is NULL

Returns: 
Number of characters written to outbuf, or if outbuf is NULL, 
returns the maximum number of characters that would have been written.
```

So the onus is on the client on whether to call the function twice.  If the client is confident that they have a buffer big enough to hold the information, then they will allocate it and call your function once using the `length` argument to limit the number of characters.

If they are not confident or want to ensure that they get all the arg information, then the client is responsible for calling your function twice, the first time with `outbuf` being NULL and getting the return value, and a second time with `outbuf` being the allocated buffer.

This is exactly how a few Windows API functions work.  The DLL allocates no memory whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

You missed one: put a deallocate function in the DLL:

```
DECL_EXPORT char * organizeArgs(const char * args) {
    ... 
    char * result = new char[outputLen];
    ...
    return result;
}

DECL_EXPORT void organizeArgsDeallocate(char *organizedArgs) {
    delete [] organizedArgs;
}
```

This is okay because the `new` and `delete` operators are called within the same DLL.

---

There's also a fourth one: use an allocation method that *isn't* different in each DLL. The problem arises in the first place because each DLL might be using a different MSVCRT DLL (C/C++ standard library). But they all have the same Win32 API DLLs, and you can share memory that's been allocated from a Win32 API function.

```
DECL_EXPORT char * organizeArgs(const char * args) {
    ... 
    char * result = (char*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, outputLen);
    // don't forget to check for NULL return value meaning out-of-memory
    // or you can pass the HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS flag
    ...
    return result;
}
// caller does HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, result)
```

Note that on Linux you generally *can* call `malloc` and `free` on different shared libraries since they are shared - you don't need to use any of these workarounds.

---

These are all valid ways to approach this problem, and in fact, you can find all of these in the standard library and the Win32 API:

- [`FormatMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage) lets you call it with a NULL buffer to calculate the size (option 1) *or* you can pass a certain flag and it will allocate the buffer with a cross-DLL-safe way (option 4).
- [`getaddrinfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo) allocates memory itself and you can free it with [`freeaddrinfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-freeaddrinfo). (option 3)
- [`asctime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/asctime-wasctime?view=msvc-160) returns a pointer to a thread-local or global buffer (option 2). (I *hope* it's thread-local, but MSDN isn't clear!)